# Species Identification: Beetle having trunk!

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Today morning I found this beetle in [*Cynodon dactylon*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cynodon_dactylon) grass. It had this beautiful head bearing a trunk like structure. I'm wondering what beetle it is

Images:

[image: Pic1]
[image: Pic2]

- Approximate size: 1.75 cm
- Temperature: 29°C
- Location: Uttar Pradesh, India

Comment: Did a bit of research. Its one of the Snout beetles from the family Curculionidae. Couldn't get any further.

Comment: Looks like a weevil (Curculionoidea). What was it's approximate size?

Comment: @theforestecologist I guess around 1.75cm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a weevil called *Cleonis japonica*. Here is a link to a specimen which was collected in 1904. (http://weevil.info/sites/weevil.info/files/Cleonis_japonica.jpg)
Here is a link to same site and one other which show where it was found.
(http://weevil.info/content/cleonis) and (https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#search)
NP means nepal. Here is a link to something which I hope is a little more descriptive.

https://www.zin.ru/Animalia/Coleoptera/pdf/arzanov_grebennikov_2017_cleonini.pdf

I wish you had taken better pictures.